# Callabable function in browser console with Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

We have an application made with Angular 9 that call an API.

The goal is to change the API URL to call the one deployed locally without having the Angular application running locally:

```
>  changeUrl("localhost:8080")

APIs URL as changed from "example.com" to "localhost:8080"
```

After this call, the application should make requests to `localhost:8080`.

Is there a way to change an Angular application variable from the browser debug console in runtime? Preferable using a custom function.

Also, where should I define this function/code to be able to call it at runtime in production mode?

Comment: you can add reference to `changeUrl` on `window` in `app.component.ts`. Then `changeUrl` will be available on `console`

Answer (score 2):

You can add attach `changeUrl` to your `window` object in your `app.component.ts` e.g

```
...
class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    (window as any).changeUrl = this.changeUrl.bind(this);
  }

  changeUrl(url) {
    //.....changeUrl implementation
  }
}
```

It can be latter called from dev console using:
`window.changeUrl(url)`